# ORM Populate entity on init

Tags: orm, coldfusion, coldfusion-9

I am using ORM in ColdFusion 9 to create my database tables as necessary using

```
this.ormSettings.dbcreate = 'update'
```

I now need to add a new model and populate it with default data.  But I only want to populate the entity if there is currently no data.

Can anyone point me in the right direction?  I have tried to search for a resolution but am not having any luck.  It is probably something simple but the solution currently escapes me.

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add something to onApplicationStart that fires off a process to check if data exists, and if not, add it.

I have done this in apps so I have data in the DB when I go to run tests.

Answer (score 3):

There is a fairly easy way to do this if you set dbcreate = "dropcreate" via providing a SQL script: 
http://help.adobe.com/en_US/ColdFusion/9.0/Developing/WS29fdb0a9aebd66bc9141f34123e5a0a3c9-8000.html

I doubt though you want to be doing dropcreate :)

So no easy solution. Either code something up possibly using onApplicationStart or just run the script in the db.